# cc -switch (or other "automatic" mechanism) to keep functions static within modules

Tags: c, static

I have two formerly stand-alone modules, say **this.c** and **that.c**, that I now want to compile together as **cc this.c that.c -o whatever**   Don't worry about just one **main()**, etc; that's all been taken care of, and everything would work okay except for the following...

Each module contains several dozen (maybe in all 50) "duplicate" functions; same names but slightly different behaviors. And I never bothered declaring them static. I started editing in that keyword, which would be lengthy-but-doable by itself. Unfortunately, I've also declared each function in every other function that calls it, so I have to edit both every function's entry point itself, as well as every function that calls any other functions. So now that's a cumbersome mess.

And please don't admonish me that the modules are too big, blah, blah, blah. Yeah, it's a mess of my own making. But my time machine's in the shop, so there's no use belaboring that point.

What I'd like to find (but can't) is some **cc -switch** that says something to the effect, **-automatically-treat-all-functions-static-in-their-own-modules** Or something like that. So, **Question:** is there any way to accomplish this without exhaustively editing pretty much everything everywhere?

(P.S. Other kinds of solutions do work, e.g., I can compile them separately and have the "main" one popen() the other one and read its output. But that makes for a cumbersome user-installation-experience which I'd like to avoid. So compiling them together is the only solution I can think of that keeps all the "internals" internal.)

Comment: "Unfortunately, I've also declared each function in every other function that calls it"  Eeh? What do you mean?

Comment: Are the functions that have same name in both module really the same or could they have a different code?

Comment: @SergeBallesta usually slightly different, e.g., new_raster()  and delete_raster() functions in each module, but the raster structs are slightly different.

Comment: @Lundin just basic K&R C syntax.

Comment: A switch like that would be equivalent to compiling an almost empty file. If none of the functions are accessible outside of their compilation unit then the only things that are observable from the outside would be variable definitions.

Comment: @JohnForkosh What's that supposed to mean? " I've also declared each function in every other function that calls it" literally means that you have this scenario in every function: `void foo (void) {  void bar (void); ... bar(); }`. Which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Art maybe, but so what? I'd imagine it's an easy enough switch for compiler maintainers to implement. And occasionally useful in exactly this kind of situation -- where two formerly separate modules have namespace collisions, and now unanticipatedly need to be compiled together. So you now need to keep their namespaces separate. And that's either a big mess or a small -switch.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, that's exactly it. Every function that calls bar() contains a declaration of bar(). (There may be a few exceptions, but it's ~90% the case.)  And you're right -- that's what it literally means...which is why I said it:)

Comment: @JohnForkosh That's too bad. If you write really weird code for no apparent reason, your program will turn into a mess, after the principle of crap in -> crap out. You should really rewrite all of this and salvage what you can while there is still time. To do anything else, such as trying to patch this together, will only inflict heavy code rot even before program release. From there, everything will escalate into a buggy, unmaintainable mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 functions with the same name but in different module, you have to use `static` keyword on both otherwise you will confuse linker when linking objects together.

So, there is no way to automatically do this for you.

Good practice is that every function which is *private* inside module should be declared as static to prevent problems you have.

If modules are between totally different (one module does not have any dependancy to another) then there is no problem at all unless you have functions with public use with the same name from both modules.

```
//This approach is OK
that.c:
static int myfunc(void) {
    return 5;
}

this.c:
static int myfunc(void) {
     return 6;
}
```

These 2 functions are totally different and are visible only inside your module.

Comment: Ok, so thanks tilz0R. I guess your answer is "no answer exists", which is an answer (i.e., God always answers your prayers, but sometimes the answer is "No":) But what about the half-edit-solution, i.e., suppose I declare myfunc() static in that.c, but don't touch it in this.c. Then will this.c still emit errors when compiled with that.c? Actually, no answer is necessary -- I'll be giving that a try and letting cc figure out what it wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

I have just recently written a code that generates a ton of random numbers and then keeps those values static (instead of recalculating the function every time I open the sheet).

```
function myFunction() {

function randnumber() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z192000");
for (var x = 1; x <= range.getWidth(); x++) {
for (var y = 1; y <= range.getHeight(); y++) {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8999999999) + 1000000000;
  range.getCell(y, x).setValue(number);
   }
 }

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheet1");
 var entries = [{
 name : "Numbers: 1-9",
 functionName : "numbers19"
  }];

 //the function above generates the random numbers and fills them in each cell 

 function copyFormulasToValues() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
 var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 
 var range = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,1,1);
     }
 }
  //the above function keeps the function static
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the question in any way.